# Editing Default Values of a column / table in postgres using Pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, ddl

How do I set the default values of a column/table in pgadmin4 if a value isn't inserted? I would like it to be 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`.

```
ALTER TABLE elbat
            ALTER COLUMN nmuloc
                         SET DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do it in Pgadmin4 interface... sorry I'm really new to this, where would I put that?

Comment: @Lego490: Somewhere, where you can put raw SQL in. I don't know any details as I don't like pgAdmin 4 and don't use it. In pgAdmin III there's a button with "SQL"  written on it in the tool bar. It's probably something similar in pgAdmin 4.